# Delete all in a spreadsheet except a Specified Range?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to delete everything in a worksheet except a specified range. The range depends on the rows of data in column 2, for which "i" gives the number of rows.

```
i = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
```

I would like keep the ranges ("A1:A" & i) and ("B1:B" & i)

There may be values in rows of A that are out of the range.

Here is code I have so far:

```
Sub Test()
   Dim i As Long
   i = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
   Dim j As Long
   j = i + 1

   .Rows("j" & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
   .Columns 'still determining how to delete columns 3 or greater

End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried something to solve your problem?

Comment: why do you start from `J` if you'd like to leave only columns `A:B` `Rows("J" & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete`?

Comment: I am trying to use the variable j which is the first row after i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you need:

```
Sub Test()
   Dim i As Long

   With Sheet1
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(i + 1 & ":" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
        .Range("C1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count - 2).ClearContents
        'or alternative way
        '.Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).ClearContents
   End With       
End Sub
```